# Nativescript - animation on a button

Tags: nativescript

I've got a button and I would like it to animate it - fade in and move up.

```html
    @keyframes ios_about_button
    {
        from { opacity: 0; transform: translate(0,40) }
        to { opacity: 1; transform: translate(0,0) }
    }
    
    Button[id='buy']
    {
        animation-name: ios_about_button;
        animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }


<Button id="buy" class="bttn-style" text="BUY" tap="{{ onSubscribeThisApp }}" opacity="0" />
```

Above is the css and xml code.

It works as expected - note the opacity="0" in the xml - trying to achieve a fade-in.

The problem is that when I tap on the button - the animation runs again.

Not sure what's going on...

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, the animation run once, can you include the of onSubscribeThisApp method.

Comment: Hey @dashman I have also tried to reproduce the issue but to no avail (using this test app https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues/tree/master/stackoverflow/buttonFade) - perhaps there is some additioal logic in `class="bttn-style"` or in `onSubscribeThisApp `

Comment: I edited my code above a little bit too much...actually the Button element has a class of "btn-primary btn-active rounded-corners bttn-style"...(I'm using nativescript-theme and SASS) - if I remove the btn-active class - then I don't get the issue.